# Data table not working in javascript But works on HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, html

My mini project was mysql table data view on data table using bootstrap.
This code execute on node server. server fetch the data with ajax.

Data table working on HTML. But javascript with mysql not working any one can help me!

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ajax-Json-Node Project</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myTable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

```
<div id="out1"></div>   
    <script>
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var showme = xmlhttp.responseText;
            convert(showme);
        };
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8081/mysql", true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function convert(show){
        var result = JSON.parse(show);
        var text_2 = "<table id='myTable'  >";
        text_2 +=   "<tr>" + 
                        "<th>product</th>" + 
                        "<th>Description</th>" + 
                        "</tr>";
        var j;
        for(j = 0; j < result.length; j++)
    {   text_2 += '<tr>' +
    '<td>' + result[j].productLine + '</td>'
     +  '<td>' + result[j].textDescription +
      '</td>' +  '</tr>';
        }
        text_2 += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = text_2; 
    }   
    </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

**Server Code**\

```
 var util = require('util'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  http = require('http'),
  url = require('url'),
  mysql = require('mysql');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
 var url_parts = url.parse(req.url);
 switch(url_parts.pathname) {
    case '/':
    display_root(url_parts.pathname, req, res);
    break;
    case '/mysql':
    display_mysql(url_parts.pathname, req, res);
    break;
    default:
    display_404(url_parts.pathname, req, res);
}
return;

function display_root(url, req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    fs.readFile('index.html', function (err, data) {
        if (err) return console.error(err); 
        res.end(data);
    });
}

function display_mysql(url, req, res) {
    getmysql(function (results){
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
        console.log("Fine");
        res.end(results);   
    });
}
function display_404(url, req, res) {
    res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write("<h1>404 Not Found</h1>");
    res.end("The page you were looking for: "+url+" can not be found");
 }
  }).listen(8081);
  console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
  function getmysql(callbackfn) {
  var query="select * from classicmodels.productlines";
  console.log("SQL Query: " + query);
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'root',
   password : '',
   database : 'classicmodels',
   multipleStatements: true
    });
connection.query(query, null, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    var resultjson = JSON.stringify(rows);
    callbackfn(resultjson);
});
connection.end();
}
```